# How to get the selected non-String object from selectOneMenu in JSF2?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to retrieve the selected item from "selectOneMenu" in case the selected item is not string.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="categoryCompId" value="#{serviceMB.selectedCategory}" converter="genericConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Category" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{serviceMB.categories}" var="category" itemLabel="#{category.name}" itemValue="#{category}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

the method `getSelectedCategory()` get called and return null value, however the method `setSelectedCategory(Category selectedCategory)` never be called

Answer (score 0):

If the value is not submited check if your `p:selectOneMenu` is placed inside the form. You should check also if your converter methods are invoked and there is no exception thrown during its invocation. I have the same usage in my code (except noselectionOption attr.) It work correctly in 5.1 verion of PF.

Comment: Yes, All these checks have been done but still the problem exist. The getSelectedCategory() is invoked but the method setSelectedCategory() never called.

Comment: setSelectedCategory() method will be invoked when the validation and conversion phases passed. If you have correctly defined converter <code>@FacesConverter</code> which implements required interface, the method should be also invoked after form submition. You can log/debug if the method getAsObject does not thrown any exception. Paste your converter here.